# Why there is no AtomicBooleanArray datatype in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have noticed that there is **NO** AtomicBooleanArray datatype in Java similar to the  AtomicIntegerArray. Although I can use AtomicBoolean[] for my current needs, I was curious to get an understanding as to why AtomicBooleanArray is NOT part of the library.

Any thoughts in this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can try asking at the [JSR166 Concurrency mailing list](http://jsr166-concurrency.10961.n7.nabble.com/)

Answer (score 3):

AtomicBoolean actually wraps a `int` which is set to 0 or 1 for false or true.  This is because it uses compareAndSwap methods which are `int` based, and not smaller.

You could implement an AtmoicBooleanArray, but not cleanly which is perhaps why it is not there. i.e. the JVM doesn't support atomic boolean operations because the CPUs like x64 and ARM don' support it.

Comment: I was aware of long and double not supporting atomic operations, but boolean is new to me. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @JProgrammer long support atomic operations and thus you can implement double atomically was well. See AtomicLong and AtomicLongArray. It is boolean which has no intrinsic support (like byte, char and short)

Answer (score 0):

I think that since AtomicIntegerArray can be see as AtomicBooleanArray, if you will assign only 0 (false) and 1 (true) values. So why to write duplicate code?

Comment: Interesting. But then my question would be why have boolean in java, as you could do away with just int?

Comment: Since Boolean is primitive type that used in almost every java program  so it was added for code readability. In addition Boolean variable presented by one bit while integer is 32 bits long.

Comment: @JProgrammer `boolean` can be 4x smaller than `int` BitSet can be 32x smaller than an `int[]`

Comment: @Maxim, thanks for the response. I am aware of the space footprint of these datatypes, but wanted to dig deeper.