# Is boolean array itself thread safe in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile

for example,

```
boolean[] booleanArray = new boolean[10];
```

I just want to make sure each single read and write is volatile.

Should I do: (I am not sure if the volatile is applied to the array or each boolean)

```
volatile boolean[] booleanArray = new boolean[10];
```

Comment: Well ... The `volatile` is applied to the variable (in your wording: to the array).

Comment: There is an [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379548/why-there-is-no-atomicbooleanarray-datatype-in-java) should explain why there is no `AtomicBooleanArray`.